# Does installing Command Line Tools for Xcode also install Git?

Tags: xcode, git

When I run `git --version` I get `git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)`, and it seems to be located at `/usr/bin/git`. I don't remember installing Git, but I *did* install Command Line Tools for Xcode in order to install Homebrew. Not a full Xcode install — just the command line tools.

I'm trying to figure out how best to update to a newer Git version, and determining how it was originally installed would be helpful. I *think* it came with the command line tools installation, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: FYI, if you're looking to install a newer git, I would recommend use Homebrew with `brew upgrade` and/or `brew install git`

Comment: @DavidPearce The more I look into this, the more I think that's the best answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Command Line Tools package does include `/usr/bin/git`. You can see what files are included in an installer by pressing command-I:

[image]

As of 10.8, OS X does not come with git preinstalled.