# Use downloaded Git instead of preinstalled Git

Tags: path, git

I am following the Lynda.com Git Essential Training. After he downloads and installs Git he enters `which git` and gets `/usr/local/git/bin/git` However when I do it I still get the preinstalled path `/usr/bin/git`

How do I change the path so I am working with my downloaded version of Git

I am using a Macbook Air - Mavericks - OS X 10.9.4 and followed the default install instructions.

Comment: There is also a Mac specific way to set paths:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106355/setting-the-system-wide-path-environment-variable-in-mavericks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following to your ~/.bash_profile

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I get the following after running which git /usr/local/git/bin//git  Is the double forward slash ok?

Comment: @Pierce Oops, left a trailing slash—fixed

Answer (score 3):

I use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), then install git using Homebrew.  This makes sure that git stays on my path, and makes it easy for me to keep git up-to-date, as well as making it easy to install other software, with its dependencies.

To install things with Homebrew, you first need to install the Xcode Command Line Tools.  StackOverflow has a great answer on [installing the command line tools on OSX 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools%20installing%20the%20command%20line%20tools%20on%2010.9).

After you have installed the Xcode Command Line Tools, you may notice that there is a git command you can use: see [Does installing Command Line Tools for Xcode also install Git?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/102073/does-installing-command-line-tools-for-xcode-also-install-git) That is not the Homebrew version of git, so it doesn't track updates.

Next, go to http://brew.sh and follow their directions for installing Homebrew.  That will install git into the Homebrew directory, and link git to `/usr/local/bin/git`.  `/usr/local/bin` should end up on your PATH before `/usr/local/git`, so you will end up using the Homebrew version of git.

After that, you can install anything for which Homebrew has a formula, including the latest versions of git. Use `brew update` to keep your index of available packages up to date, and `brew doctor` to verify that your Homebrew configuration is correct.  Then you can use `brew upgrade git` to keep your git at the latest version available to Homebrew.